# DFT for partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I find it difficult to find the example of DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) that solve partial differential equation. Would you mind to give me an example? From the equation that should solved until step by step solve it using DFT. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The finite fourier transform is a technique possibly used when solving boundary value problems for linear PDE's.

Defining

$$S_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x)\sin{\frac{n \pi x}{L}} \, dx$$

to be the finite fourier sine-transform, it's inverse is given by

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n \sin{\frac{n \pi x}{L}} $$

A problem appropriate for this method would be something like

$$u_{tt} = u_{xx} + \sin{\pi x}, u(0,t)=0, u(1,t)=0, u(x,0)=1,u_t(x,0)=0$$
on the domain $[0,1] \times [0,\infty)$.

Comment: Can I say that Discrete Fourier Transform is about Discrete Sine Transform or Discrete Cosine Transform? Or DST and DCT is way to solve DFT?

Comment: You can use DFT for these problems as well, it's just that the imposing boundary problems will annihilate the cosine term in the complex exponential of the series.